# Functional use of Array.includes causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would expect `[1].some([1].includes)` to return true, instead I get an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Any ideas what would cause this? As I understand, `Array.some` accepts a function invoked per array item, which `[1].includes` should fulfill.

Comment: _“This question has nothing to do with `this`”_ — It has _everything_ to do with `this`. Just because _you_ didn’t type `this` yourself, it doesn’t mean it’s not there. It _is_ there; see the [specification for `Array.prototype.includes`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes): Step 1: “Let _O_ be ? ToObject(**this** value).”. It’s used right there in the first step. The linked Q&A and [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](/q/3127429/4642212) explain how passing `[1].includes` as a parameter loses the base context from which the `this` value is derived.

Comment: You are right, thanks for clarifying; I misunderstood.  Edited that content out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lose the context when you pass that function as is: when it's invoked as a callback, value of `this` inside it is `undefined` in strict mode (and global object in non-strict mode), not `[1]`. To address this issue, you may fix the context:

```
[1].some([].includes.bind([1]))
```

Note that it doesn't matter which array is used to access `includes` function; you might as well write that as...

```
[1].some( Array.prototype.includes.bind([1]) )
```

That's be a bit less concise, but a bit more efficient (as no immediate array is created). Still, it almost never should be a bottleneck; thus you should better optimize for readability.

---

Unfortunately, this won't be enough. See, [**Array.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses *two* parameters:

```
arr.includes(searchElement[, fromIndex])
```

... and [**Array.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) *does* supply it with those two (even three in fact, but only two are used by `includes`). That's why this...

```
[1,2,3].some([].includes.bind([1])); // true
```

... works, but this...

```
[2,1,3].some([].includes.bind([1])); // false
```

... doesn't: the lookups in `[1]` array start from 0th, 1st, 2nd elements - and apparently fail after the first one.

To fix this, you might either create a function that takes exactly one argument with something like lodash's [**_.unary**](https://lodash.com/docs/#unary):

```
[2,1,3].some(_.unary([].includes.bind([1]))) // now we're talking!
```

... or bite the bullet and use arrow function instead. Note that you can still use a function with a bound context here:

```
const checker = [].includes.bind([1]);
[2,1,3].some(el => checker(el));
```

... to make this more flexible.

Comment: Great answer. I was unaware a second argument could be provided to Array#includes.  Probably a good illustration of why using variable arity functions point-free is a bit of a footgun.  Having thought about this, my preference would be for the lambda function now, for clarity if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific implementation of `includes` in whatever JS engine you are using, but usually the standard library functions are not very co-operative for point-free style programming.

Generally this is because the context (`this`) is not assigned as intended.  This can be shown by trying the following:

```
[1].some([1].includes); // Error
[1].some([1].includes.bind([1])) // true
```

Edit: This answer is not entirely correct. You should probably read rain77ow's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273240/5932623)